# Grails plugin dependency issue, WAR file missing plugin artifacts

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, dependency-management, buildconfiguration

Developing a Grails 1.3.7 web app; it depends on a plugin which depends on another plugin, the diagram below illustrates the dependency configuration.

The problem is the WAR file; I'm using the standard `grails war` command, but the classes for `core-plugin` are not packaged in the war; the artifacts for `webutil-plugin`, however, are present. I double-checked Artifactory, no issues with the repository. One thing I noticed in the WAR build output was...the `webutil` plugin is pulled from the repo first, then the WAR is packaged, then, the `core` plugin is pulled and copied to my local grails/ivy repo. Not sure why this is happening, could it be because the web app implicitly depends on `core` through `webutil`?

[image]

Comment: JIRA defect related to this issue, http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5624, did not resolve my problem since I was creating new plugin version, not updating an existing snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get around this by adding both plugins to web apps `BuildConfig`, although this is not ideal since it results in a redundant configuration. Still not sure why the implicit dependency doesn't work.

[image]